# iterating over an array while copying only integers to another in js

Tags: javascript

I have tried iterating over the array `holder2` while copying it's integer elements to another array `temp`. But it doesn't seem to work as the content of `temp` remained the same.

```
var holder=getElementById("userinput").value;
var holder2=holder.split(" ");
var temp =[];

for(vari=0;i<holder2.length;i++){
  if(isNaN(holder2[i])===false){
    temp[i]=holder2[i];
  }
}
```

Comment: [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 2):

That's not how you add an element to an array in Javascript. What you're looking for is [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

```
temp.push(holder2[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that you want integers only and that `temp` is empty.  I'd suggest verifying that elements are integers and then using `Array.push()`.

```
var holder=getElementById("userinput").value;
var holder2=holder.split(" ");
var temp =[];

for(var i=0;i<holder2.length;i++){
  if(isNaN(holder2[i])===false && holder2[i] % 1 === 0){
    temp.push(holder2[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var holder=getElementById("userinput").value;
var holder2=holder.split(" ");
var temp =[];

for(var i=0;i<holder2.length;i++){
    var num = parseInt(holder2[i])
    if(isNaN(num)===false){
        temp.push(num)
    }
}
```